# What will increase the tension?

Tags: waves, string

I know from the equation $v=\sqrt{T/\mu}$ that increasing the tension will increase the velocity. However is it the same for if you increase the velocity, the tension will increase? Or does increasing $\mu$ result in tension to increase?

Comment: Welcome on physics SE :) You might want to add what system this equation is for and where the equation is from to make answering correctly easier. Also, any thoughts of your own will be appreciated :) Finally, I took the liberty of retyping the formulas, you can find more about that here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Related : [Does increasing the tension on a string also increase the density?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169820)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing cause and effect. The tension in a guitar string, and the mass of the string, are factors (causes) which determine the speed of a wave on the string (the effect). You cannot change the speed of the wave and expect that to alter the tension or mass of the string. That would be like expecting that you can make a car engine more powerful by towing the car faster along the motorway.

That is why the equation is written as $v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$ to emphasise that $v$ is the dependent variable (the effect) while $T$ and $\mu$ are the independent variables (the causes).

The equation only tells you how $v$ depends on $T$ and $\mu$. It does not tell you how these independent variables might be related to each other. In theory they are independent of each other. In practice, increasing $T$ will stretch the wire, reducing $\mu$.