# Does increasing the tension on a string also increase the density

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, density, string

Does increasing the tension on a string also increase the wave speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does increasing the tension on a string also increase the density?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169820/)

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Your question is unfortunately a bit inappropriate for this format as you do not provide much detail and do not show any of your own thoughts or research attempts. This is generally badly received here. You might want to visit the help centre on the top of the page and do the tour to get a feel of the website.

Comment: Density or wave speed?  Which are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the wave speed is proportional to the square root of the tension, because tension provides the restoring force that allows the wave to propagate.